# WSDL modified to included complex type now request not encoded correctly

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, cobol, cics

I have an original wsdl from thirdparty service.
Simplified.

```
<s:element name="ProcessRequest">
  <s:complexType>
     <s:sequence>
       <s:element minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1" name="strXMLInput" type="s:string"/>              
     </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

I have modified for CICS Web Service Assistant that generates a COBOL copybook to represent the xml that should be sent to the service.

Simplified.

```
<s:element name="ProcessRequest">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element  name="strXMLInput" >
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                 <s:element name="ACORD">
                    <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                     <s:element name="SignonRq">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                                        <s:element name="CustLoginId">
                             <s:simpleType>
                                 <s:restrictionbase="s:string"  >
                                  <s:length value="10"/>
                                       </s:restriction>
                            </s:simpleType>
                            </s:element>
```

I haved changed the wsdl so my copybook will have all the elements to send the correct ACORD xml to service instead of building a lengthy string in cobol. 
With WireShark I captured the request to service and is completely document xml not encoded, the correct request so be

```
    <ProcessRequest><strXMLInput>&gt:Acord....etc,
```

but with my mod I'm sending

```
     <ProcessRequest><strXMLInput><Acord....etc.//actual doc xml
```

Is there anyway I can make this work with the expanded wsdl and let mainframe know that strXMLInput is still a string but with children, or any other ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to embed XML inside an item in your SOAP data stream.  That would require a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section.  CICS TS version 4 doesn't support this directly, I'm not sure about version 5.

I believe you can create an [XML-aware application](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/tasks/dfhws_xml_provider.html) and get closer to the result you desire.

Update:

I misunderstood what you're doing, this is a requester not a provider, right? If that's the case then I believe you need to LINK to DFHPIRT directly.  It's covered in the topic after the one I pointed you to, [Creating an XML-aware service requester application](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/tasks/dfhws_xml_requester.html).

Comment: We are on 4.2 currently, I tried the aware attribute added to dfhws2ls but it was ignored, might be due to mapping level. Any ideas how I could insert a CDATA in the copybook/wsdl. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I ended up revising my wsdl/copybook generate to take string input in one element, then used my custom copybook with all the acord elements, then I use the cobol xml generate on the copybook and moved it into the string input element. This gives me more control and I can use preexisting pipelines and configurations for CICS. Thanks